# Analyze REST API performance

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, rest

Are there any tools to analyze the REST API performance specifically the response time, to figure out why API is slow ? These APIs are built using spring boot

Comment: I believe `Postman` ( or `newman`) or any other such API tool has the capability to show what time your API takes including the TCP handshake, data transfer etc. If you are not using such tools, I think better to implement our own version of API performance, you may put start and end time difference to actually calculate how much time your API is taking overall as well as you can trace each method and return a consolidated figure of the response